# Postgres 13: Update column when MV refresh is complete

Tags: update, materialized-view, postgresql-13

I have what feels like a very simple operation I wish to perform, but cannot find any guidance.

I have an application that allows users to upload a series of files with records, which get processed into tables, and then aggregated results made available for display. The aggregations are a bit slow, even with indexes, because the tables aren't very wide so postgres prefers to skip the indexes.
My solution was to use a materialized view, but I need to wait for the refresh to finish before letting users request their data.

There's already a table which keeps track of the state of submission processing, so when a submission goes from "processing" to "done" I have a trigger which sees that update, refreshes the MV, and I want it to then update a different column on the submission table saying that the view has been refreshed and the data is ready to view.

I have a function intended to do this:

```
create or replace function my_function() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
begin
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY my_special_mv;
    update mySubmissionsTable set custom_column = 'Complete' where id = NEW.id;
    RETURN NULL;
end;
$$;
```

If I remove the "update" line, it works exactly as expected, nice and fast.
If I leave the update in, it spins and spins forever.

My trigger looks like

```
create CONSTRAINT trigger myTriggerName
after update
on mySubmissionsTable 
deferrable initially deferred
for each row
when (NEW.submissionStatus = 'Created')
execute procedure my_function();
```

The MV definition doesn't touch mySubmissionsTable, so not a mutual locking issue (I think).

**tl;dr** How can I detect that the refresh of a materialized view is finished and update a record accordingly? I'm not wedded to doing all in one function, though it helps that it has access to the NEW record from the trigger to limit the scope of the update.